# Tomcat can't find mysql-connector-java-8.0.30.jar that I put in the WEB-INF/lib/

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, servlets, jdbc

I put `mysql-connector-java-8.0.30.jar` in WEB-INF/lib/
Tomcat thows:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/school
        at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:702)
        at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:228)
        at cn.korilweb.dao.StudentDao.selectAllStudents(StudentDao.java:27)
        at cn.korilweb.servlet.StudentServlet.doGet(StudentServlet.java:23)
```

But it can work when I put `mysql-connector-java-8.0.30.jar` in `D:\apache-tomcat-8.5.61\lib\`

### Environment Information:

1. My Computer System: Windows 10
2. Java Version: java 11.0.16.1
3. Tomcat Path: D:\apache-tomcat-8.5.61\
4. MySQL Version: mysql  Ver 8.0.22 for Win64 on x86_64
5. MySQL Driver Version: mysql-connector-java-8.0.30.jar

I started MySQL on my local machine, username is root, passward is 123456.
I wrote a simple servlet--`StudentServlet`, the `StudentServlet` used `StudentDao` to retrieve student's data from MySQL.

### Code:

`StudentServlet.java`

```
package cn.korilweb.servlet;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import cn.korilweb.dao.StudentDao;
import cn.korilweb.entity.Student;
import java.util.List;

public class StudentServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private StudentDao dao = new StudentDao();

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) {
        
        try {
            PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();
            List<Student> students = dao.selectAllStudents();
        
            for (Student s : students) {
                out.println(s);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

---

`StudentDao.java`

```
package cn.korilweb.dao;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import cn.korilweb.entity.Student;

public class StudentDao {
    final String JDBC_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/school";
    final String USER = "root";
    final String PASSWARD = "123456";

    public List<Student> selectAllStudents() throws Exception {
        List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM student";
        System.out.println("sql: " + sql);
        try (
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(JDBC_URL, USER, PASSWARD);
            Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(sql)
        ) {
            while (rs.next()) {
                int id = rs.getInt(1);
                String name = rs.getString(2);
                int age = rs.getInt(3);
                
                Student s = new Student();
                s.setId(id);
                s.setName(name);
                s.setAge(age);

                students.add(s);
            }
        }
        return students;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        StudentDao dao = new StudentDao();
        List<Student> students = dao.selectAllStudents();
        for (Student s : students) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

---

`Student.java`

```
package cn.korilweb.entity;

public class Student {
    
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int age;

    // Some getter, setter, toString method
}
```

---

`web.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                      http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
  version="3.1"
  metadata-complete="true">

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>StudentServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>cn.korilweb.servlet.StudentServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>StudentServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/students</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

---

### My trial

I wrote a `main` method in `StudentDao` to test, and it works!
here is my cmd result:

```
> javac -cp .;..\lib\mysql-connector-java-8.0.30.jar cn\korilweb\dao\StudentDao.java

> java -cp .;..\lib\mysql-connector-java-8.0.30.jar cn.korilweb.dao.StudentDao
sql: SELECT * FROM student
Student [id=1, name=djh, age=23]
-----------
sql: INSERT INTO student VALUES (2, "lzq", 24)
```

After that,I put these classes in `D:\apache-tomcat-8.5.61\webapps\student-app\`, here is my directory structure:

```
D:\apache-tomcat-8.5.61\webapps
                          └─student-app
                                └─WEB-INF               
                                    ├─classes           
                                    │  └─cn             
                                    │      └─korilweb   
                                    │          ├─dao
                                    │          │  └─StudentDao.class
                                    │          │
                                    │          ├─entity
                                    │          │   └─Student.class
                                    │          │
                                    │          └─servlet
                                    │               └─StudentServlet.class
                                    │
                                    ├─lib
                                    │  ├─javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar
                                    │  │
                                    │  └─mysql-connector-java-8.0.30.jar
                                    │
                                    └─web.xml
```

I run `D:\apache-tomcat-8.5.61\bin\startup.bat` to start Tomcat Server on my local machine, and input`http://127.0.0.1:8080/student-app/students` in browser, then I got the Exception Message:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/school
        at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:702)
        at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:228)
        at cn.korilweb.dao.StudentDao.selectAllStudents(StudentDao.java:27)
        ...
```

---

### My Problem

After google this problem, I try to put `mysql-connector-java-8.0.30.jar` in `D:\apache-tomcat-8.5.61\lib\`, and I found it can work, but why? I can't understand, please help me.

I intentionally not use IDEA, Maven to help me build first simple web project because I want to know the steps of manual operation without advanced tools.

Comment: You shouldn't use `DriverManager.getConnection` in a web application, use a `DataSource` backed by a connection pool. However, the problem is that automatic driver loading doesn't work in this case. For Tomcat, it only works when the driver is in Tomcat's `lib` directory, not in the `WEB-INF/lib` of a WAR, and you need to explicitly load the driver using `Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver")` in this case.

Comment: Please remove **javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar** from WEB-INF\lib, Tomcat has it already on <<CATALINA_HOME>>\lib folder.